# PreparedStatement: How to insert data into multiple tables using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Could somebody tell me whether the first `stmt.close();` required in the following JDBC code, for executing two different SQL queries against two different tables?

```
public class MyService {
    private Connection connection = null;

    public void save(Book book) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "password"); 

            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PUBLISHER (CODE, PUBLISHER_NAME) VALUES (?, ?)");
            stmt.setString(1, book.getPublisher().getCode());   
            stmt.setString(2, book.getPublisher().getName());           
            stmt.executeUpdate();

            stmt.close(); //1

            stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BOOK (ISBN, BOOK_NAME, PUBLISHER_CODE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            stmt.setString(1, book.getIsbn());  
            stmt.setString(2, book.getName());
            stmt.setString(3, book.getPublisher().getCode());
            stmt.executeUpdate();

            stmt.close(); //2       
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
        finally { connection.close(); }         
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I remember `close()` is used to release JDBC resources

Comment: Every `PreparedStatement` needs to be closed after use, so, yes, you need two `#close`, as you have two `PreparedStatements`. Better would be, to close both of them in the `finally` block, as you do with the `Connection`
, though.

Comment: Yes, as otherwise you're not closing the first prepared statement object. You should also consider using try-with-resources to avoid not closing statements if exceptions occur.

Comment: It is not required: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my book, I would always recommend closing resources that have been opened to avoid possible leaks.

A slightly more modern way would be to use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "password")) {

    try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PUBLISHER (CODE, PUBLISHER_NAME) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
        stmt.setString(1, book.getPublisher().getCode());   
        stmt.setString(2, book.getPublisher().getName());           
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    // stmt is auto closed here, even if SQLException is thrown

    try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BOOK (ISBN, BOOK_NAME, PUBLISHER_CODE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        stmt.setString(1, book.getIsbn());  
        stmt.setString(2, book.getName());
        stmt.setString(3, book.getPublisher().getCode());
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    // stmt is auto closed here, even if SQLException is thrown
}
// connection is auto closed here, even if SQLException is thrown
```

Comment: How about adding an example of the same but in a batch, say we're looping over a collection of books and publishers, preparing a batch to be executed outside the loop.

Comment: That would be a different question.

Comment: Requires Java 1.7 or better.

Answer (score 4):

It is a common misconception with statements that closing them releases all that preparing them built. This is wrong. The optimisation that results in the preparation of the statement is performed by the database. It is then stored/cached by the database and usually re-used next time the statement is prepared.

As a result, prepared statements can be closed and prepared as often as you wish - the database will recognise the same statement next time around and recover the cached preparations it made last time - if it wishes to.

In summary - **yes**, statements should be closed - and **no**, this does **not** reduce the effectiveness of your queries.

Answer (score 1):

It is not required but it is recommended. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close()

The next line after the first `close()` in your code assigns a new value to the reference `stmt`, so the object you use to execute the first insert will be GC'd and closed eventually. It is good practice to go ahead and close it when you know you're done with it. This releases the JDBC resources immediately.

Comment: But what if for whatever reason the GC finaliser fails to close the resources properly and due to connection pooling the resources stay associated with a connection that isn't closed, so the statement resources keep building up. I'm not saying that this necessarily will happen, only that I wouldn't be surprised that it wouldn't happen depending on the implementation of the jdbc driver, so I personally would want to see all resources closed and would consider not doing so as a possible leak/bug.

Answer (score 1):

Its good practice to close the Statement handle as it will release the JDBC & Database resources. You can read more about stmt.close() [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29)

I would like to point out that its good to close your Statement object in finally block so that DB resources are released even if an Exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both the stmt.close() methods are necessary.
You should always explicitly close the Statement or PreparedStatement object to ensure proper cleanup.

Comment: Are you sure they're necessary? Can you provide a reference? This says otherwise: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close()

Comment: Document says the same thing : Its good practice to close the statements. I am trying to highlight the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
 try{
     String insertIntoCust = "insert into NORTHWIND_CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,CITY,STATE,POSTAL_CODE) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
     pst = connect.prepareStatement(insertIntoCust);
     pst.setString(1, txtCustomerId.getText());
     pst.setString(2, txtFirstName.getText());
     pst.setString(3, txtLastName.getText());
     pst.setString(4, txtAddress2.getText());
     pst.setString(5, txtCity.getText());
     pst.setString(6, txtState.getText());
     pst.setString(7, txtPostalCode.getText());

     pst.execute();

     String insertIntoOrder = "insert into NORTHWIND_ORDER(ORDER_ID,ORDER_DATE) values(?,?)";
     pst = connect.prepareStatement(insertIntoOrder);
     pst.setString(1, txtOrderId.getText());
     pst.setString(2, txtOrderDate.getText());

     pst.execute();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");
 }catch(Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
 }
```

With the code above, I could insert data into multiple tables with one button. The pst.execute need to be inserted in both queries; if not, the query that have the pst.execute is the table that will receive the data.